# Bind dropdown using an http xml response

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I'm only a beginer with XML and ASP.NET. My requirement is to bind a dropdown using an xml response received from a thirdparty service say geonames.org. As an example I'd like to bind my dropdown with Country names from that xml response. So how can I make it possible.

This is an example from geonames.org

http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?username=[myusername]

and below the response XML

```
<geonames>
<country>
<countryCode>AD</countryCode>
<countryName>Andorra</countryName>
<isoNumeric>020</isoNumeric>
<isoAlpha3>AND</isoAlpha3>
<fipsCode>AN</fipsCode>
<continent>EU</continent>
<continentName>Europe</continentName>
<capital>Andorra la Vella</capital>
<areaInSqKm>468.0</areaInSqKm>
<population>84000</population>
<currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
<languages>ca</languages>
<geonameId>3041565</geonameId>
<west>1.4071867141112762</west>
<north>42.65604389629997</north>
<east>1.7865427778319827</east>
<south>42.42849259876837</south>
</country>
<country>
<countryCode>AE</countryCode>
<countryName>United Arab Emirates</countryName>
<isoNumeric>784</isoNumeric>
<isoAlpha3>ARE</isoAlpha3>
<fipsCode>AE</fipsCode>
<continent>AS</continent>
<continentName>Asia</continentName>
<capital>Abu Dhabi</capital>
<areaInSqKm>82880.0</areaInSqKm>
<population>4975593</population>
<currencyCode>AED</currencyCode>
<languages>ar-AE,fa,en,hi,ur</languages>
<geonameId>290557</geonameId>
<west>51.58332824707031</west>
<north>26.08415985107422</north>
<east>56.38166046142578</east>
<south>22.633329391479492</south>
</country>
---------------
---------------
etc.....
```

So from the above URL, that will return an XML in this structure.. So how can use that to bind my dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET  provides the XmlDataSource control for accessing data marked up in XML.

You can then bind like this :

```
ddlStatus.DataSource = iObjDropDownRetrieval.GetXMLDataSource("~/XMLDatasource/FacilityStatus.xml");
ddlStatus.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlStatus.DataValueField = "Value";
ddlStatus.DataBind();
```

Comment: Sorry for my less knowledge in that area. My question is how can I use the XML response from that thrirdparty URL for this purpose. That means from http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?username=[myusername]